# What license version should I use for an open-source PyQt5 application on GitHub

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, license-recommendation

On the [Riverbank License FAQ](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/license-faq) for PyQt5 it specifies that PyQt5 is under the license GPL. I'm not sure whether I should use GPLv1, GPLv2 or GPLv3.

What license should I choose and it is MIT compatible? Would I be able to put my application under the MIT license even though PyQt5 uses GPL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the documentation, PyQt5 is licensed under GPLv3.  https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#license

Your application would also have to be licensed as GPLv3 (or a compatible license).

As I understand it you would not be able to use MIT license for your application. There is a certain asymmetry here, a GPL application may use an MIT library, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks! That really cleared some things up, I didn't want my project to be under the wrong license as that could cause quite the trouble.

Comment: The application *can* be licensed under the MIT license, but you can't take advantage of the extra permissions that the MIT gives you as long as the application depends on GPL-licensed code.